# AWS Alexa skills kit SDK for node.js: Error when deploying

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

Both my model and skill.json are up to date when I check `ask diff`, I made some changes to the lambda function in `index.js`, and when I tried to `ask deploy`, I got this error message:

```
[Error]: Failed to resolve the Lambda deploy state for arn:aws:lambda:xxx. Please make sure this Lambda resource is correctly mapped to the existing alexaUsage in the config file.
```

My understanding is that the `config` file is populated automatically and I didn't make any change to it... I'd appreciate it a lot if someone can help me understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have more than one profile configured in .ask/cli_config.

You can also back-up this file and create an empty cli_config file then execute `ask init` in the corresponding folder project to reconfigure the access token for the right account.